# Reverse to specific Bootstrap-Tab with Django CBV get_success_url()

Tags: django, django-bootstrap4

I'm using Bootstrap Tabs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs

Is there a way to reverse to a specific Tab with get_success_url() ?

Someting like (but this does not work):

```
class UpdateModelView(UpdateView):
    model = Model

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '{}#profile'.format(reverse('myApp'))
```

Update:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a tab with `id="secondTab"`? What if you manually add the anchor to the URI?

Comment: I updated the question a little. When i change URI to http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp#profile it is not changing to the profile-Tab, but i can navigate through the tabs by clicking it. Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: shouldnt this be `#profile-tab`? (so with a `-tab` suffix)?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/#profile-tab doesnt work either